# Integral of a complex function (contour integral)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

This is the integral:
$$\int_{\gamma}z^2\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$$
we know that:

$\gamma$ is a simple closed curve;
$f$ is analytical in $R$ (the region bounded by the curve) and in all the points of the curve; $f$ has only one zero of order $n$ in $R$.

What I attempted to do is the following:

First I tried with integration by parts, and since $\gamma$ is closed, i have $\int_{\gamma}z\log(f(z))dz$, but I have no idea how to further procede since complex logarithm isn't continuous as far as I know.

Then I tried with  $f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ where $g(z_0)\neq 0$ and then applied Cauchy's formula, but that didn't lead me to anywhere either. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you can extract this as the $c_{-2}$ Laurent coefficient of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\ln f(z)$ and reverse engineer from there

Comment: You can get the result immediately from the [generalised argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle).

Comment: @projectilemotion wow that's exactly it. Thank you so much!